# Digital Signature/ eSign verification fails

Tags: pdf, itext, adobe, digital-signature

I have a eSigned / Digitally signed PDF, the document is signed  using iText lib in detached signature. I am having issue while verifying the signature, getting message "signers identity is invalid because it has expired or not yet valid" and in signer info "There were errors building the path from signers certificate to an issuer  certificate."

I have tried many ways to validate the signature but couldn't get any success. If I explicitly add signers certificate as trusted certificate then I get a green check and able to verify the signature but I think  thats not the correct way to do it.

Adobe Signature setting are as follow:-
[image: signature verification preferences]

digitally signed pdf can be found here[digitally signed document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_p4l1pjzGEtZOKhX8hS97Gv1wSj9FmXx/view?usp=sharing)

can anyone please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried many ways to validate the signature but couldn't get any success.

That is not surprising: Your signature *is not valid*. In the PDF signature field value there is a signing time 2020/06/11 09:28:35 GMT but your signer certificate is valid not before 2020/06/11 09:29:44 GMT and not after 2020/06/11 09:59:44 GMT. At the claimed signing time, therefore, your signer certificate was not valid yet and could not create a valid signature.

Apparently you sign using a signing service that creates a short-time certificate just in time when your signature request to it arrives. Unfortunately that is after the time iText stored as signing time in the PDF at the beginning of the signing process.

*Thus, **one way to resolve the issue** is to tell iText to use a time slightly (e.g. two minutes) in the future.*

You can do that by means of the `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `setSignDate`.

Your signature actually also violates a *recommendation* from the specification: The afore mentioned signing time stored in the signature field value dictionary *should be used only when the time of signing is not available in the signature* (the embedded signature container). In your case, though, the embedded signature container does contain a `signingTime` signed attribute with value `11/06/2020 09:29:44 GMT` which is *not* before the start of certificate validity.

As that only is a recommendation, your PDF signature is not made invalid by having two signing time values. But as the values differ, this can result in different verification results by different validators, using either one or the other value.

*Thus, **another way to resolve the issue** is to make sure no signing time value is added to the signature value dictionary at all.* This additionally makes your signed PDF follow the recommendation above and so be more precise.

Unfortunately using the `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `setSignDate` to set a `null` value does not work, later on in the signing process this results in `NullPointerException` occurrence. But if you use a custom `ExternalSignatureContainer` implementation in your signing code (and not an `ExternalSignature` implementation), you can remove that entry in your `modifySigningDictionary` implementation. The key is `PdfName.M`.

---

As an aside, as your signing certificate is only valid for half an hour, validators may also reject it if their validation policy only trusts digital time stamps, not unsecured date-time values.

Thus, you should add revocation information and digitally time stamp the whole construct during the life time of the certificate to guarantee long term validation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining the issue in that much detail,now got clear picture what I was doing wrong.
First approach you have suggested can work as a quick fix but the second one looks more perfect. I would like to add embedded signature containers signingTime and Signer information also as I do not have signers name also in advance  because external singing service returns public certificate with signing response only. Is it possible to achieve this with ExternalSignatureContainer, if yes any sample code snippet will be helpful.

Comment: @mlk The external sign service does not provide revocation info as the certificates are used for one time sign only, How can I deal with long term validation without revocation info.

Is there any way to rectify the issue with already signed doc(as attached in his post) and  set the signing time from embedded signature container instead of the one set in appearance before sign. As far as I know its not possible, It might sound a stupid doubt but please clarify. Thanks :)

Comment: *"Is there any way to rectify the issue with already signed doc"* - if it was possible to change relevant properties of a signature like that without signing again, the signing scheme would not be worth a dime. Your signature is invalid (or at least ambiguous with one interpretation that is invalid). Full stop. To get a signature that doesn't have an invalid interpretation, you need to sign again (or convince standardization committees to change standards to make your signatures clearly valid).

Comment: *"The external sign service does not provide revocation info as the certificates are used for one time sign only"* - that doesn't make sense if those signatures shall be validated by standard components like Adobe reader. How should a validator know? A validator has to assume that any regular signing certificate can be revoked any time. Thus, it needs to be able to check revocation status. I do know some similar services that return the relevant revocation information together with the signature. Otherwise crls or ocsp responders are a must.

Comment: *"I would like to add embedded signature containers signingTime and Signer information also"* - stop. I said you can prevent itext from setting its own signing time. But not that you can change any previous information. E.g. if you have information in the signature visualization, you can change it usually only with Adobe reader at least showing a warning that  something was changed.

Comment: "The external sign service does not provide revocation info as the certificates are used for one time sign only" - Whoever told you this, that person does not appear to know the signing service in question. According to the certificate in question there is a CRL distribution point at [https://esign.cdac.in/ca/esignCA2019.crl](https://esign.cdac.in/ca/esignCA2019.crl), and at that location you can download a current CRL...

Comment: Thanks a lot for valueable inputs and time.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what your issue is. There's a whole new way of solving it, in 3 steps.

1. Open in Adobe Acrobat DC or any Adobe pdf editor software you have.
2. In Edit, go to Preferences, in the end come to Signatures. Click on verification, more, in verification time section, select current time. Same location, verification information section, select never.
3. In Windows integration, tick validating signatures and validating certified documents. Click ok.

Close all popups. Come back to signature area and right click to select, validate signature.
Done ✅

Comment: Changing verification settings like that may make *your* Acrobat app positively validate that signature. But usually it's not *your* Adobe app that matters but the validators *of the recipients* of your signed documents that do. And why should *they* twist the configuration of *their* validators like that?